# Android Studio, ProGuard unable to compute hash of Classes.jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

It has been long years, if ever since I've asked a question at StackOverflow. Although I use it almost of daily basis.
Anyway; here it goes:

Recently I've switched to API 23; that forced me to use

```
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

as they've thrown out an easy access to the apache library.

My project compiles fine and runs fine across all test-devices in debug mode.
Today I need to bring my project to production and ProGuard shouts with

> Unable to compute hash of (..) \build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar'

there are no other errors or warning. There used to be but I got rid of them. Like getting rid of duplicate copies of apache libraries.

Here is my Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.0.4') {
        exclude module: 'joda-time'
    }
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.1'
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.8.0'
    compile ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-translate:v2-rev41-1.20.0')
            {
                // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
                exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'shared'
                exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
                exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
                exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
            }
    compile ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc')
            {
                // Exclude artifacts that the Android SDK/Runtime provides.
                exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'shared'
                exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
                exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
                exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
            }

    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.0.10@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.0.+"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+"
    compile (
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.4.1'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.4.1']
    )
    compile 'de.undercouch:bson4jackson:2.4.0'

}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
    'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
    'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
    'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

}
```

and here goes the proguard-rules.txt

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\android-sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Only obfuscate


-dontshrink

# Keep source file and line numbers for better crash logs
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# Avoid throws declarations getting removed from retrofit service definitions
-keepattributes Exceptions

# Allow obfuscation of android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**
# to avoid problem on Samsung 4.2.2 devices with appcompat v21
# see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

# Amazon IAP library has some missing stuff
-dontwarn com.amazon.**

# ButterKnife uses some annotations not available on Android.
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
# Prevent ButterKnife annotations from getting renamed.
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}

# Eventbus methods can not be renamed.
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
}

# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

# joda-time has some annotations we don't care about.
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**

# OkHttp has some internal stuff not available on Android.
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.**

# Okio has some stuff not available on Android.
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Oltu has some stuff not available on Android (javax.servlet), we don't use (slf4j)
# and not included because it is available on Android (json).
-dontwarn javax.servlet.http.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**

# Retrofit has some optional dependencies we don't use.
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.**
```

I've cleaned my project; restarted Android Stuio even wiped out the whole Builds directory.

```
Result:
Information:Gradle tasks [:Application:assembleRelease]
:Application:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:checkReleaseManifest
:Application:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGithubLzyzsdCircleprogress110Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase780Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation780Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps780Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby780Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComTheartofdevEdmodoAndroidImageCropper104Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareComViewpagerindicatorLibrary241Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareMeLeolinShortcutBadger1010Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareNetDanlewAndroidJoda281Library UP-TO-DATE
:Application:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Application:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Application:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:Application:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Application:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:Application:lintVitalRelease
:Application:proguardRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Application:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Application:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:Application:packageRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:packageRelease'.
> Unable to compute hash of C:\Users\rafal_000\Projekty\Application\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 6.694 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: try `./gradlew clean assembleRelease` and see if you get your proguard warnings then

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the Gradlew utility! It seems to be something used internally by Android Studio right? It showed me warnings not visible while building in Adnroid studio. There was a problem with Java environment variable and one more thing I recall. I dunno how to mark this as an answer or assign any points to you.

Answer (score 1):

As Iagreen has noted in his comment; I used the gradlew command line utility to get more detailed errors. It turned out there was a problem with JAVA_HOME variable. Solved.

Comment: This command: `./gradlew connectedDevDebugAndroidTest --stacktrace`